# Max Recursion Exhausted before Statement Completion

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I know this has been asked and answered a few times here, but I can't seem to find the answer to my specific problem. Here's the recursive query:

```
    CTE as (

    SELECT 
    ZipCode
    ,Age
    ,[Population]
    ,Deaths
    ,DeathRate
    ,Death_Proportion
    ,DeathProbablity
    ,SurvivalProbablity
    ,PersonsAlive

    FROM ProbabilityTable
    WHERE Age = 0
    
    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
     p.ZipCode
    ,p.Age
    ,p.[Population]
    ,p.Deaths
    ,p.DeathRate
    ,p.Death_Proportion
    ,p.DeathProbablity
    ,p.SurvivalProbablity
    ,LAG(c.PersonsAlive,1) OVER(PARTITION BY p.ZipCode ORDER BY p.Age) * p.SurvivalProbablity

    FROM ProbabilityTable p
    INNER JOIN CTE c
    ON p.ZipCode = c.ZipCode
     and p.Age = c.Age
    WHERE p.Age < 86
    )
```

In the ProbabilityTable PersonsAlive is set to 100,000 when Age = 0. What I'm looking to do with the recursive CTE is multiple the previous value of PersonsAlive by the current SurvivalProbability to calculate the PersonsAlive of that Age. Age goes up to 85 so that's why I have my termination clause set at 86.

I've tried tweaking the recursive part of the query a number of times (and also setting PersonsAlive to 100,000 in the anchor part) but I can't figure it out. This is my first attempt at a recursive query and even with some course work it's not clicking for me.

**EDIT**

Here is the updated code that actually runs:

```
   CTE as (
     SELECT 
     ZipCode
     ,Age
     ,[Population]
     ,Deaths
     ,DeathRate
     ,Death_Proportion
     ,DeathProbablity
     ,SurvivalProbablity
    ,PersonsAlive

    FROM ProbabilityTable
    WHERE Age = 0

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
     p.ZipCode
    ,p.Age
    ,p.[Population]
    ,p.Deaths
    ,p.DeathRate
    ,p.Death_Proportion
    ,p.DeathProbablity
    ,p.SurvivalProbablity
    ,LAG(c.PersonsAlive,1) OVER(PARTITION BY p.ZipCode ORDER BY p.Age) * p.SurvivalProbablity

  FROM ProbabilityTable p
  INNER JOIN CTE c
  ON p.ZipCode = c.ZipCode
     and p.Age = c.Age + 1
  WHERE p.Age < 6
```

)

And here is the results it returns:

[image: Results]

What I want the results to be for PersonsAlive is as follows:

[image: Correct Results]

So with each iteration of the CTE, it needs to reference the previous row of PersonsAlive and the current row of SurvivalProbability to calculate PersonsAlive

Comment: The error is telling you the query is wrong. The JOIN condition can easily join a row to itself, resulting in infinite recursion. You should probably replace `WHERE p.Age < 86` with `WHERE p.Age !=0 AND p.Age < 86`, otherwise a root row can join to itself

Comment: Please provide some sample data. "*with the recursive CTE is multiple the **previous value** of PersonsAlive by the **current** SurvivalProbability*" - How do you relate two rows?...what criteria determines row 1 is the previous row of row 2, the current row? Panagiotis is correct in theory, but his suggested fix will cause the join to fail and return no rows in the second half of the `UNION ALL` because `c.Age` is only `0`, which is how you're currently relating `p` and `c`, by `Age`. This is why you're only getting 1 row back with his change (from the first half of the `UNION ALL` clause).

Comment: Post a sample of the data and what you want to produce. The JOIN conditions  can't be satisfied - since `Age =0` and `p.Age = c.Age` are used you'll either get self-joins or root rows. You don't need a recursive CTE to get the previous `PersonsAlive` by age, the LAG expression `LAG(PersonsAlive,1) OVER(PARTITION BY ZipCode ORDER BY Age)` returns just that already

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test this without your raw data but I think your issue is you're lagging over the previous row, causing your frame of reference to be 2 rows back.

When you're using a recursive CTE, you already have access to the previous row, via `CTE c`. When you do `LAG(c.PersonsAlive,1)` you're actually telling it to look at `PersonsAlive` from 2 rows back from the current row (lagging 1 row back from the previous row).

Since on the first recursive pass, there is only 1 row back, the `LAG()` function will return `NULL` by default since there is no 2 rows back at that point. This is why every row in your results has `NULL` for the `PersonsAlive` column, except for the first row (anchor row from the first half of your `UNION ALL` clause). So if you remove the `LAG()` function from it and instead just do `c.PersonsAlive * p.SurvivalProbablity`, you should get all of the expected `PersonsAlive` values.

That being said, a recursive CTE seems like overkill here and you probably can just use the `LAG()` window function in a static call on your `ProbabilityTable` like so:

```
SELECT 
    ZipCode,
    Age,
    [Population],
    Deaths,
    DeathRate,
    Death_Proportion,
    DeathProbablity,
    SurvivalProbablity,
    ISNULL(LAG(PersonsAlive,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ZipCode ORDER BY Age), PersonsAlive) AS PersonsAlive
FROM ProbabilityTable
```

As I mentioned, I can't really test this, so please let me know if you run into any issues, and I'll help you accordingly.

Recursive CTEs are good for tree-like problems, e.g. when you need to compare multiple child rows to their parent, or interact with multiple levels of the tree simultaneously. Window functions like `LAG()` allow you to interact with any single row at a time relative to the current row. Your problem seems to be the latter kind.